# Can't use resources from resx after they being re added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, resx

First a little explanation:
For the first time I've added images from various folders. Some time later I've decided to "put in order" the mixed files in my project root folder. Ok, after I've done, my resource file naturally lost the files because of their paths were changed, so I just deleted them from *.resx and re added with the same name to prevent the name conflict.

Ok so the problem is:
After I've added images back they no longer viewing in the IDE... well... in fact, the resources are in the *.resx file, I can see them in there, but after I assign them to the picture box, for example, it just doesn't display... Adding them with the other name also doesn't help... It seems that *.resx file become broken... also, the assignment code erased from my form's designer code. BUT the application is still compiling WITH THE IMAGE!

explanation images are attached with links, can't attach them in another way due to lack of reputation.

PS: sorry for maybe bad english...

http://puu.sh/5uC4T

http://puu.sh/5uC63

Comment: Have you Cleaned the project? And try viewing the resx file in XML or the designer view, the filenames should be in there.

Comment: I've already solved it by creating a new one resource file, but, anyway, interesting why it happens...

Comment: So your problem is solved? Good to hear! Please close the question, or write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as for me the best way is to create new *.resx and link. Solved.